# Difference between version pip show and importlib.metadata.version

Tags: python, pip, python-importlib

I am creating a module, henceforth called *mymodule*, which I distribute using a *pyproject.toml*. This file contains a version number. I would like to write this version number in the logfile of *mymodule*. In *mymodule* I use the following snippet (in `__init__.py`) to obtain the version:

```py
import importlib.metadata

__version__ = importlib.metadata.version(__package__)

del importlib.metadata
```

However this version is wrong. This appears to be the highest version which I have ever installed. For reference the command `python3 -m pip show mypackage` does actually show the correct version after installing the module locally. I struggle to explain this difference. Can anyone think of a cause of this discrepancy?

I also ran `importlib.metadata.version(mypackage)` which returned the same incorrect version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to left over build artifacts from using `setup.py`. `importlib` and `pkg_resources` will detect these artifacts in a local installation and `pip` will not. Deleting the `mypackage.egg-info` directory fixed the issue.

Comment: Seems like you should accept your own answer. It seems like it is the correct one to me.

Comment: I need to wait 24 hours for that but will do it later